# Is openssl '-batch' command line option deprecated or hidden?

Tags: security, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have figured out a set of SSL commands (using openssl tool) to create the private key, CSR and ultimately, the certificate.

Root key and certificate:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private/ca.key.pem 4096
openssl req -config openssl.cnf -key private/ca.key.pem -new -x509 -days 7300 -sha256 -extensions v3_ca -out certs/ca.cert.pem
```

Client SSL key and certificate:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private/client.key.pem 2048
openssl req -config openssl.cnf -key private/client.key.pem -new -sha256 -out csr/client.csr.pem
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -extensions usr_cert -days 375 -notext -md sha256 -in csr/client.csr.pem -out certs/client.cert.pem
```

However, at the third step of client SSL certificate creation, the tool asks couple of further (interactive) questions as follows:

```
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -extensions server_cert -days 375 -notext -md sha256 -in csr/www.example.com.csr.pem -out certs/www.example.com.cert.pem
Using configuration from openssl.cnf
Enter pass phrase for /Users/myssl/private/ca.key.pem:
Check that the request matches the signature
Signature ok
Certificate Details:
        Serial Number: 4096 (0x1000)
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 31 18:43:27 2017 GMT
            Not After : Nov 10 18:43:27 2018 GMT
        Subject:
            countryName               = IN
            stateOrProvinceName       = KAR
            organizationName          = ABC
            commonName                = www.example.com
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            Netscape Cert Type: 
                SSL Server
            Netscape Comment: 
                OpenSSL Generated Server Certificate
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                D7:12:DB:DE:D1:92:52:15:E5:AD:83:84:B6:7F:9F:CF:97:06:91:8E
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:1C:5F:64:BB:8B:E5:8E:A7:DE:00:E2:D7:1A:D5:1D:52:53:5E:59:32
                DirName:/C=IN/ST=KAR/L=BLR/O=ABC/CN=www.example.com
                serial:C3:D6:EE:B0:FE:28:76:14

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
Certificate is to be certified until Nov 10 18:43:27 2018 GMT (375 days)
Sign the certificate? [y/n]:y


1 out of 1 certificate requests certified, commit? [y/n]y
Write out database with 1 new entries
Data Base Updated
```

The above two prompts goes off only after adding the '-batch' option to the command line. However, I did not find any mention or help on the 'man openssl' page.

I am using openssl version 1.0.2k. Is this option deprecated or it is hidden? It still works and makes the above command non-interactive.

Comment: The manpage for openssl(1) covers only a few options (`-help` and `-pass*`) shared by nearly all 'commands'; the **manpage for ca(1)** covers the options specific to the `ca` command including `-batch`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.